# Applying OFFSET and LIMIT separately to subsections of a result

Tags: mysql, limit

This is my first post here, so apologies if I'm breaking protocol.

I have a single table which for sake of argument I'll call t1, the table looks like:

```
id -- primary key
fk_id -- foreign key
date_created
```

I have a set of fk_id from a prior query.

Here is a query that returns exactly what I want, but uses UNION, and would be very inefficient for the hundreds or possibly thousands of fk_id I may have to search on:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM t1
   WHERE fk_id = ?
ORDER BY date_created DESC
   LIMIT m, n
UNION
  SELECT *
    FROM t1
   WHERE fk_id = ?
ORDER BY date_created DESC
   LIMIT m, n
UNION -- ... for each fk_id
```

Note that the values m and n for offset and limit are the same for each UNION.

What I'd like is a query that doesn't use a UNION and instead says something like

```
WHERE fk_id IN (?, ?, ?, ...)
```

but retains the separate application of LIMIT to each subset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a row number to each fk.  The best way is probably to use variables:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             (@rn := if(@f = fk_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@f := fk_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) rn
      FROM t1 CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @f := -1, @rn := 0) vars
      ORDER BY fk_id, date_created DESC
     ) t
WHERE rn >= m and rn < m + n;
```

EDIT:

If only MySQL supported the following (almost) ANSI syntax, then this might be more efficient:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where t1.id in (select id
                from t1 tt1
                where tt1.fk_id = t1.fk_id
                order by date_created desc
                limit m, n
               );
```

I'm not 100% sure, but this should take advantage of indexes on `t1(fk_id, date_created)` and `t1(id)`.  If it uses these indexes, then it should work pretty well.

Comment: "That's crazy, but it might just work!" :-) - thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for this, the second example errors with `ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'` but your first answer works, there's an off-by-one error on `WHERE rn >= m and rn < m + n;` because `@rn` is 1-indexed, and my primary and foreign keys aren't numeric, but thanks so much, my SQL wasn't up to that.

Comment: @BillHails . . . Oops, I forgot that limitation of MySQL.  The syntax works in most other databases.